# android studio 1.5 not running my app

Tags: android-studio

I was using android studio 1.3 and my app were running fine. I decided to upgrade to version 1.5 and now I don't see my app running.  the android phone comes up by my app doesn't start. there is no error. I decided to create a new application with just a button but still app is not running. only the android avd comes up but app doesn't start. even when I look through all the apps I am  not able to find mine.  any ideas how to solve the problem?